# Is it possible to delete a package within SSIS Catalog?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2016

Seems it could not be done in SSMS. Does Microsoft actually provide this option for users to delete single package within SSIS catalog? Thanks.

Best Regards,
Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft has added **Incremental package deployment** in SQL 2016 - This feature lets you deploy one or more packages to an existing or new project without deploying the whole project.

As Incremental package deployment has been added, I believe, decremental for single package is not there. There are no any SPs other than `catalog.delete_project, Folder and Environments` in SSIS catalog ([Projects and Packages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh479588.aspx)).

Answer (score 2):

What I did is this:

I looked for the `project_ID` from `[SSISDB].[internal].[projects]`. We have Dev/QA and UAT packages deployed on same server under different projects, which is why I looked for the `project_ID`.

[image: Project DB sanpshot]

Then I just ran the delete script on `[SSISDB].[internal].[packages]`

```
 delete from [SSISDB].[internal].[packages] where project_id=3 and name like '%your package name%'
```

Comment: For SQL Server 2016-2022. Deletion of the latest package version record from [SSISDB].[internal].[packages] does remove package from Object Explorer, but DOES NOT remove it from SSISDB. This can be checked by exporting project, "deleted" package will be present in *.ispac file among other packages. If new single package deployed to the project,  "deleted" package appears again. When a single package deployed, a new project version is created under the hood and stored in [SSISDB].[internal].[object_versions] in varbinary format. SSISDB does not store code of a separate *.dtsx packages.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, no. The SSIS db catalog uses a new project-based deployment model that encapsulates your entire project in a `ZIP` archive and deploys that archive to the server (called an `.ispac`). See [Deploy Integration Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213290.aspx) for more info.

At best you could delete the current project and deploy an updated one using [catalog.delete_project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878158.aspx) and [catalog.deploy_project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878004.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Wrapped it in a TRAN

BEGIN       TRAN

--SELECT    *

DELETE [pkg]

FROM

[SSISDB].[internal].[projects] AS [proj]        WITH (NOLOCK)

INNER JOIN

[SSISDB].[internal].[packages] AS [pkg]     WITH (NOLOCK)   ON

[pkg].[project_id] = [proj].[project_id]

WHERE

[proj].[name]       =   'MyProject'

AND [pkg].[name]    =   'MyPackage.dtsx'

--      COMMIT

--      ROLLBACK TRAN

Comment: Maybe take out the comments...at least.